# Do I need to buy a MySQL License?

Tags: mysql, license, licensing

I am building a non open source web project and using MySQL database.

Do I need to pay for a MySQL license or not? and why?

Comment: I believe that [this question from stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225987/can-someone-explain-mysqls-license-and-what-it-means-to-closed-source-developme) explains it well.

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic, but I think you can find what you need at [MySQL's](http://www.mysql.com/about/legal/licensing/index.html) web page.

Answer (score 1):

Information from the MySQL-Website:

> MySQL AB provides its software (database server, connectors, tools)
> under a number of flexible licenses, designed to meet the usage and
> distribution requirements of different types of users:
>
> **For Open Source Projects:** If you are developing and distributing open
> source applications under the GPL License, then you are free to use
> MySQL under the GPL License. More Info » If you are developing and
> distributing open source applications under an OSI-Approved License,
> but not the GPL, MySQL provides the GPL License with a FLOSS
> Exception.
>
> **For Commercial OEMs, ISVs and VARs:** For OEMs,
> ISVs, and VARs who distribute MySQL with their products, and do not
> license and distribute their source code under the GPL, MySQL provides
> a flexible OEM Commercial License.
>
> **For Web Sites,
> Enterprise IT, and Government IT:** MySQL Enterprise is the
> comprehensive subscription offering that provides database developers
> and DBAs with everything they need to successfully develop and deploy
> database solutions with MySQL. It includes Certified Software, updates
> and upgrades, proactive alerts and advisors, the online MySQL
> Knowledge Base, and full production-level technical support. The
> Certified Software (database server, connectors) is provided under the
> GPL License. Optionally, customers may choose a Commercial License.
>
> At MySQL AB we believe in open source software. We encourage everyone
> to publish open source software under the GPL License.

So it depends of the categorie of your project if you must/mustn't use a commecial licence.
[Source](http://www.mysql.com/about/legal/licensing/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to do all the hosting for your web project and run MySQL on your server(s), then you don't.

If you're going to sell/distribute your web project (perhaps as an "appliance" of some sort) and bundle MySQL in your distribution, then you do.